# Cell height increases after scroll or reload

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have dynamic cell for chat table. I have message label and time lable. Contraints are as follows

message label leading >=100

message label trailing = 15

message label top =10

message label bottom to time label top = 5

time label to bottom = 5

time label width 60 and height 21

time label trailing =15

I tried lot with content Hugging and comprassion values.
Message label **Content Hugging property** is

Horizontal 250

Vertical 1000

**Compression Resistance**

Horizontal 250

Vertical 1000

It correctly calculates height first time. **But when I add new cell when message is send or received, go back and come back to same view, its height increases more 1500**. Here is code to find height for row.

```
-(CGFloat)heightForCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    MessageCentreService *message = [[self.dic_messages objectForKey:[self.array_dates objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static AttendieChatTableViewCell *sizingRightCell = nil;
    static AttendieChatTableViewCell *sizingLeftCell = nil;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sizingLeftCell = [self.tableView_attendeeChatList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellChatLeftIdentifier];
        sizingRightCell = [self.tableView_attendeeChatList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellChatRightIdentifier];
    });


    sizingLeftCell.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetWidth([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds), CGRectGetHeight(sizingLeftCell.bounds));
    sizingRightCell.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetWidth(self.tableView_attendeeChatList.frame), CGRectGetHeight(sizingRightCell.bounds));

    if(message.message_type == 1)
    {
        sizingLeftCell.label_message.text = message.message_text;
        sizingLeftCell.label_messageTime.text = @"10.30 pm";

        [sizingLeftCell setNeedsLayout];
        [sizingLeftCell layoutIfNeeded];

        CGSize size = [sizingLeftCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];

        return size.height;
    }
    else
    {
        sizingRightCell.label_message.text = message.message_text;
        sizingRightCell.label_messageTime.text = @"10.30 pm";
        [sizingRightCell setNeedsLayout];
        [sizingRightCell layoutIfNeeded];
        CGSize size = [sizingRightCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
        return size.height;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems with systemLayoutSizeFittingSize, i fixed that by setting the preferredMaxLayoutWidth of labels.

Comment: I want my lable to be dynamic in width also. trailing is set to >= 100.   When I set prefered width, then also it shows odd behaviour.